# Can we take an integer array (representing a binary tree) & produce a new array as though traversing input in an in-order manner w/o building tree?

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I am solving a question where we are given an `array of integers`. We want to insert these numbers in a `binary tree` in an `in-order fashion`.

e.g. if we were given the following input `[1, 2, 2, 6, 7, 5]`, and if we were to build a `binary tree` out of it, it would look like this:

[image]

We are then asked to do a `breadth-first search traversal` of this `binary tree` and return the nodes.

The conceptual solution I came up with is to create a `Binary Tree class` and build the binary tree from the input array, following an in-order traversal, then simply walking the tree using BFS while recording the nodes in an array, then returning this array.

But is there a way to avoid building the whole tree and to transform the `input array` into an array that would represent it in an `in-order manner` by iterating over the input somehow? But then we'd still have to do a BFS on this?- so is there a known/common way to do this too without building the tree itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use striding ranges to iterate through the positions corresponding to each level of the tree.  The number of levels can be obtained using the bit_length() method on the length of the list. each level strides by the corresponding power of 2 starting at the previous power of two (in a one-based numbering scheme):

```
def getBFT(L):
    for n in range(len(L).bit_length(),0,-1):   # levels
        for p in range(1<<(n-1),len(L)+1,1<<n): # striding by 2^n
            yield L[p-1]    


L = [1, 2, 2, 6, 7, 5]

print(*getBFT(L)) # 6 2 5 1 2 7
```

Given positions numbered from 1, as 1,2,3,4,5,6

- level 3 strides from 4, stepping by 8:  4      (top)
- level 2 strides from 2, stepping by 4:  2,6
- level 1 strides from 1, stepping by 2:  1,3,5  (bottom)

Levels are processed in decreasing order and positions are adjusted for zero based indexing.